# Hooking into a C++ Program with Java

Tags: java, c++

I have a question. Is it do able to hook into a C++ program with Java? And what do I need/make? Because I dont have any Idea how I could do it. I researched already in the internet but I didn't find something that could me help.
I'm very interested in it. ^^

~ Dragon (;

Comment: What do you mean by "hook into", and what kind of "program"? You should perhaps show some code you already have to help you explain what is the concrete, specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **[Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)**.

> In computing, the Java Native Interface (JNI) is a programming framework that enables Java code running in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to call and be called by native applications (programs specific to a hardware and operating system platform) and libraries written in other languages such as C, C++ and assembly.

These links might be helpful.

- **[Wrapping up a C++ API in Java or .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767009/wrapping-up-a-c-api-in-java-or-net)**
- **http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html**
- **http://thebreakfastpost.com/2012/01/21/wrapping-a-c-library-with-jni-introduction/**

Comment: You might also find JNA useful. (See https://github.com/twall/jna) JNA is built on top of JNI and is slightly easier to use in some cases.

Comment: Even though this is right, it will still be hooking using C or C++ and not Java itself..